# Different screen configurations for different users?

Tags: x11, multi-monitor, xubuntu

I have a machine running Xubuntu 20.04 with three monitors. Currently, I have it configured with a separate screen for each monitor (displays :0.0, :0.1, and :0.2), which works well for its intended purpose. But for other uses, it would be better to have a single screen across all three monitors (all three on display :0.0). I achieved this setup using
nvidia-settings, which appears to modify /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings:  version 470.57.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1920 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 3840 0
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

This configuration seems to affect all users. How can I set up one user with the three screen configuration, while other users have all three monitors as a single screen?

Comment: The display configuration for most (if not all) window managers is separate for each user. So the answer is yes, it is possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Xorg.conf is a configuration file that is used by the X/Xorg server when it is started up. If you're using a display manager such as GDM, LightDM, or SDDM, then this happens when those start, which is before a user logs in. As far as I know there is not an easy way to switch between having Separate X screens and one virtual display across all monitors at the user level. It may be possible to start in multiuser mode, have users log into the terminal and start the X server/desktop environment. To get per user configs. What desktop environment, display manager, and window managers are you using?

Comment: @Natolio: I'm using XFCE desktop. I see lightdm and xfwm4 processes running, which I presume are the display manager and window manager, respectively.

Comment: So with XFCE you have 3 X screens each with their own workspace/display for your user. For other users you would like XFCE, but with one workspace/display across all monitors?

Comment: @Natolio: Essentially, yes.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with something that could do this. I do not think there is a way to do it using a display manager, but perhaps something a little nonstandard from multiuser mode. Maybe just a simple shell script that selected the xorg.conf to use before starting X, or something fancier than that using xorg.conf.d. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: Were you able to give the answer a try? And if so did you run into any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A per user X server configuration is not really a thing as far as I know, but if the other users are comfortable logging into the console in the `multi-user.target` then doing this is possible.

You can switch to the multi-user.target in run time by running `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target`.

To make this the default runlevel, you can run:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

As a side note...to get back to the graphical mode use the same commands, but with `graphical.target`:

```
sudo systemctl enable graphical.target
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

In multi-user mode you will just have a text based interface, but you can start the X server using the command `startx`. By default `startx` just uses whatever is in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

However, if you set the environment variable `XORGCONFIG` then `startx` will use whichever file specified under `/etc/X11/`.

For example you would create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.fred` to have the X server started with separate X screens. Then from the console (in multi-user mode) you would run:

```
export XORGCONFIG=xorg.conf.fred
startx
```

This will start up your default Desktop Environment.

Then when you logged out of your Desktop Environment you would be returned the multi-user mode shell that you launched it from and would also have to log out from that shell.

For other users you would need to create a separate configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.notfred` containing the configuration for 1 virtual screen across all 3 monitors. Then when a different user logs in (again still in multi-user) the would run:

```
export XORGCONFIG=xorg.conf.notfred
startx
```

This would launch the default Desktop Environment for them and again would return them to the logged in shell (multi-user mode) when they logged out from the Desktop Environment.

For what it's worth, this is not standard at all and you may run into other issues launching the desktop environment in this way that you may not have otherwise, so your mileage may vary, but I do think it would accomplish what you are asking for. Let me know if it works or if you run into issues and I can update the answer as needed.

Comment: This is some good information. I've been trying some things. I found the XORGCONFIG environment variable doesn't seem to have any affect, but I can do something along the lines of `startx -- -config xorg.conf.fred`. I'm not sure how to get the desktop I want (always brings up Gnome, it seems). Still working things out, but this helped me a lot.

Comment: There may be a command called `startxfce` or `startxfce4`. Start with that, if it isn't there then I have some other ideas to have it launch the proper environment. Glad `startx -- -config` works for you.